Is the principal eigenvalue of the clamped plate minimized by the equilateral triangle among all triangles of a given area?
Let $\Omega$ be a ``nice'' domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$
(bounded and with piecewise smooth boundary). Consider the clamped plate eigenvalue problem, given by
$$\Delta^2 u = \lambda u $$
$$ u|_{\partial \Omega} \equiv 0,\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\Big|_{\Omega} \equiv 0.$$
Here $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian (which I denote to be the negative of the
second derivative) and $\Delta^2$ denotes the bi-laplacian
(Laplacian applied twice). The term
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ denotes the derviatve of $u$ in the normal direction
to the boundary.
It is a well known fact that eigenvalues exist, are positive, are countable
and hence can be ordered
as $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots$. Let us denote $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ to be the first eigenvalue (also called the principal eigenvalue).
Let us now impose the condition that $\Omega$ is a triangle and the area of $\Omega$
is fixed. Is it true that among all trainagles, the equilateral triangle minimzes
the principal eigenvalue for the clamped plate?
Remark: This statement (for triangles) is true for the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem
(where you simply have the Laplacian instead of the bi-Laplacian
and the boundary condition is that the eigenfunction
vanishes on the boundary....no conditions on the normal derivative here).
It is also true for both the Dirchlet probelm and
the clamped plate problem that among all domains of a
given area, the disc minimizes the principal eigenvalue.
For the Dirichlet problem, the solution is obtained through Schwarz symmetrization.
This argument does not work for the clamped plate problem and a
significant amount of work is needed to actually prove it.
My question is about the triangle. For the Dirichlet problem, the solution
is obtained through Steiner symmetrization through one of the altitudes.
One then argues that by Steiner symmetrization, the principal Dirichlet
eigenvalue reduces. Is there any analogous fact for the principal eignevalue
of the clamped plate?
